# How to generate a vector containing a numeric sequence with a given step?

Tags: r

I have a decimal variable x0.

I want to make a vector from [x0, 6] increasing by 0.01 each time.

I know it's something like `c(x0:6, by=0.01)` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
x0 = 5.9
seq(x0, 6, 0.01)
 [1] 5.90 5.91 5.92 5.93 5.94 5.95 5.96 5.97 5.98 5.99 6.00
```

Comment: You could make it shorter by cheating. `x0:600/100`

Comment: Nope! That sequence starts at `x0/100`; you'd need to do `(x0*100):600/100`, which is longer than using `seq` if you take out the spaces =)