# R numbers from 1 to 100

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate a vector containing a numeric sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133413/how-to-generate-a-vector-containing-a-numeric-sequence)

In R, how can I get the list of numbers from 1 to 100? Other languages have a function 'range' to do this. R's range does something else entirely.

```
> range(1,100)
[1]   1 100
```

Comment: Your questions are clear and concise, so I suspect you can get thru one of the "intro to R" online pages or the totorials such as http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf  in a short time. I'm suggesting this only because RTFM-ing is likely to be a lot faster and more useful to  you than posting questions at this level.

Comment: Thanks Carl that link is great. Now I understand the difference between `[[]]` and `[]`

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Your mistake is looking for `range`, which gives you the `range` of a vector, for example:

```
range(c(10, -5, 100))
```

gives

```
 -5 100
```

Instead, look at the `:` operator to give sequences (with a step size of one):

```
1:100
```

or you can use the `seq` function to have a bit more control. For example,

```
##Step size of 2
seq(1, 100, by=2)
```

or

```
##length.out: desired length of the sequence
seq(1, 100, length.out=5)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need the construct for a quick example to play with, use the : operator.

But if you are creating a vector/range of numbers dynamically, then use seq() instead.

Let's say you are creating the vector/range of numbers from a to b with a:b, and you expect it to be an increasing series. Then, if b is evaluated to be less than a, you will get a decreasing sequence  but you will never be notified about it, and your program will continue to execute with the wrong kind of input.

In this case, if you use seq(), you can set the sign of the *by* argument to match the direction of your sequence, and an error will be raised if they do not match. For example,

```
seq(a, b, -1)
```

will raise an error for a=2, b=6, because the coder expected a decreasing sequence.