# R vector - return all items of vector if vector is defined by minimum/maximum

Tags: r, vector

Let's say I have the following vector:

```
vector <- c(0, 5)
```

`0` here defines my minimum, `10` defines my my maximum.

```
min <- min(vector)
```

now I want to return all values, that are between `0` and `5`:

```
fullvector <- c(min, min+1, min+2, min+3, min+4)
```

Of course that fails If the number of items changes, so what is a better way to write this?

Comment: understand my vector as defining a minimum and a maximum, now I want to return the full range of that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R numbers from 1 to 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454333/r-numbers-from-1-to-100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that in your question `10` should be replaced with `5`?

Then what you ask for is obtained as follows

```
vector <- c(0, 5)
min_value <- min(vector)
max_value <- max(vector)
fullvector <- min_value:max_value
## [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use `range`

```
Reduce(`:`, range(vector))
#[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5
```